# Spectrum of operator $(Tx)_{i}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\alpha_{j}x_{i+j}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

> **Note:** Please do not give a solution; I would prefer guidance to help me complete the question myself. Thank you.

---

Let $\alpha_{0},\ldots,\alpha_{n}\in\mathbb{C}$ be given. Compute the spectrum of $T:\ell^{1}\rightarrow\ell^{1}$ with
\begin{align}
(Tx)_{i}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\alpha_{j}x_{i+j}\text{ for all }i\geq 1.
\end{align}

**My Solution**

I am only to find a bound on the spectrum. Let us look at the $\ell^{1}$ norm of the image of $T$.
\begin{align}
|Tx|_{1}&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\bigg|\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{j}x_{i+j}\bigg|\\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|\alpha_{j}||x_{i+j}|\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(|\alpha_{0}||x_{i+0}|+|\alpha_{1}||x_{i+1}|+\ldots+|\alpha_{n}||x_{i+n}|)\\
&= |\alpha_{0}|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_{i}|+|\alpha_{1}|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_{i+1}|+\ldots+|\alpha_{n}|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_{i+n}|\\
&=|\alpha_{0}||x|_{1}+|\alpha_{1}||Lx|_{1}+|\alpha_{2}||L^{2}x|_{1}+\ldots+|\alpha_{n}||L^{n}x|_{1}\\
&\leq \sum_{j=0}^{n}|\alpha_{j}|,
\end{align}
where $L:\ell^{1}\rightarrow\ell^{1}$ is the left shift operator. By picking the sequence $(L^{n-1}x)_{n\geq 1}$ this shows that $\|T\|=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|\alpha_{j}|$. So $\text{spr}(T)\leq \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|\alpha_{j}|$, where $\text{spr}(T)$ denotes the spectral radius of $T$.

Can someone give me some guidance on where to progress to from here? **Please no answers, just hints.**

**Completion of the proof**

Observe by expanding the series you can rewrite $Tx$ as the polynomial of some other operator.
\begin{align}
Tx &= (\sum_{j=0}^{n}\alpha_{j}x_{1+j},\sum_{j=0}^{n}\alpha_{j}x_{2+j},\sum_{j=0}^{n}\alpha_{j}x_{3+j},\ldots)\\
&= (\alpha_{0}x_{1}+\alpha_{1}x_{2}+\ldots+\alpha_{n}x_{n+1},\\
&\hspace{22.5mm} \alpha_{0}x_{2}+\alpha_{1}x_{3}+\ldots+\alpha_{n}x_{n+2},\\
&\hspace{37.5mm} \alpha_{0}x_{3}+\alpha_{1}x_{4}+\ldots+\alpha_{n}x_{n+3},\ldots)\\
&=(\alpha_{0}x_{1},\alpha_{0}x_{2},\ldots,\ldots) + (\alpha_{1}x_{2},\alpha_{1}x_{3},\ldots) + \cdots +(\alpha_{n}x_{n+1},\alpha_{n}x_{n+2},\ldots)\\
&=\alpha_{0}x + \alpha_{1}Lx + \alpha_{2}L^{2}x + \cdots +\alpha_{n}L^{n}x\\
&=(\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}L+\alpha_{2}L^{2}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}L^{n})x.
\end{align}

Therefore the spectrum of $T$ is equal to the polynomial of the spectrum by the spectral mapping theorem. That is,
\begin{align}
\sigma(T)&=\sigma(\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}L+\alpha_{2}L^{2}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}L^{2})\\
&=\alpha_{0}\sigma(I)+\alpha_{1}\sigma(L)+\alpha_{2}\sigma(L^{2})+\cdots+\alpha_{n}\sigma(L^{n})\\
&= \alpha_{0}\sigma(I)+\alpha_{1}\sigma(L)+\alpha_{2}\sigma(L)^{2}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}\sigma(L)^{n}.
\end{align}

Now, $\sigma(L)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}||\lambda|\leq 1\}$, from a previous question I completed.Therefore,
\begin{align}
\sigma(T) = \{\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}\lambda +\alpha_{2}\lambda^{2}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}\lambda^{n}\in\mathbb{C}||\lambda|\leq 1\}.
\end{align}
We know $\text{spr}(T)\leq\sum_{j=0}^{n}|\alpha_{j}|$ and,
\begin{align}
\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(T)}|\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}\lambda+\alpha_{2}\lambda^{2}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}\lambda^{n}|\leq|\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}|\leq\sum_{j=0}^{n}|\alpha_{j}|,
\end{align}
hence we have found the entire spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an elementary way of doing this. The key observation is that $T=p(S)$, where $p$ is a polynomial and $S$ is the unilateral shift 
$$
Sx=(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots). 
$$
So the Spectral Mapping Theorem reduces the problem to finding the spectrum of $S$. This is still non-obvious, as far as I can tell, but one can consider the adjoint $S^*:\ell^\infty\to\ell^\infty$. The spectrum of $S^*$ is easy to calculate, as it is almost entirely made up of eigenvalues. Then using $\sigma(S)=\sigma(S^*)$ (another non-trivial fact for operators on Banach spaces as opposed to Hilbert spaces) we are done.

Comment: Yes. I have completed the problem now. It does require the spectral mapping theorem.